# How to find what Activity.runOnUiThread overrides in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

When I see the source code of Activity.java, I see `@Override`, but what does it override? Is there a way to jump to the method in the parent interfaces/classes that is being overridden in Android Studio?

```
@Override
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a mistake to mark `runOnUiThread`  with `@Override`. Even Android studio show the error indicating

> Method does not override method from its super class

I had also checked the entire hierarch upto `Context` and no other parent class has `runOnUiThread`

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I also saw that warning, but I thought those talented developers at Google would have made such a mistake on this important class, so I thought there was some hidden class somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this icon (green circle with red upside arrow) to go to the overriden method declaration[image]